# How can I pass a parameter to a URL when using Url.Action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
function reload() {
    var referenceID = $('#ReferenceID').val();
    $('#detailData').load(Url.Action("DetailData", new { pk = referenceID }));
}
```

It points to a syntax error on the "=" just after pk.

How can I load the contents of a URL and pass referenceID as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `@` sign:

```
function reload() {
    var referenceID = $('#ReferenceID').val();
    $('#detailData').load('@Url.Action("DetailData", new { pk = referenceID })');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a ' missing

This: `$('#detailData').load(Url.Action("DetailData", new { pk = referenceID }));`

Will be something like this in JavaScript

`$('#detailData').load(yoursite/subsite?some_param=value);`

You put a string value into load, but there is no '

Additionally, you cant mix c# and JavaScript the way you are trying it to do.

Try this:

```
function reload() {
    var referenceID = $('#ReferenceID').val();
    $('#detailData').load('yoursite/subsite?pk=' + referenceID);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Hardcoding URL strings into an MVC app is a bad idea. The helpers are there for a reason