# Why is Hardcoding URL strings into an MVC app is a bad idea? (Or is it?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In a comment [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876395/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-url-when-using-url-action), [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) mentions that

> Hardcoding URL strings into an MVC app is a bad idea. The helpers are there for a reason

Is this so? If so, why?

Comment: +1 for taking time to check on a comment's validity :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Url generation is the result of route configuration in your application's global.asax. When you use helpers like ActionLink, they inspect route configuration and generate routes accordingly.

If you change your route configuration later, or install application to virtual directory, URLS generated by helpers in whole application get changed dynamically, so you don't have to inspect and change every hardcoded URL string by hand, and your application is less likely to break.

If you want to markup anchors, you can use [UrlHelper.Action Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx). Internally all of the helpers which depend on URL generation, use this method.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logon", "Account")">logon<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had written a small site that had the URLs hardcoded into it.  I tend to avoid the practice now due to the headache it causes of having to change all the URLs as soon as you push to production.

This was a small webapp, and it still drove me up a wall. I would follow that advice :)

Comment: The URLs this question is about don't change when pushing to production unless using virtual directories. This is more about controller and action names.

Comment: While the referenced question was about controller/action names, this question was asked about why the aforementioned comment was true.  I simply mention this as another reason why URLs should not be hardcoded

Answer (score -1):

I would rather not use Url.Action("Logon","Account"), as it is hardcoded and any change to action name, its difficult to identify.

Better we can write a Extension like,

```
     public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink<TController>(this HtmlHelper helper,
 Expression<Func<TController, object>> expression, string displayText)
            {
                string controller = typeof(TController).GetControllerName();
                string action = expression.GetActionName();

                return helper.ActionLink(displayText, action, controller);
            }
```

and then use it in the view like,

```
@Html.Action<AccountController>(a=>a.Logon(),"Click here")
```

Comment: This is already in Futures, right? And there's a non-negligable performance penalty; there's a report with numbers somewhere...

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: Yes, it has some performance issue, But if your server is scaled enough... It can be taken into consideration. as per [This Link](http://devlicio.us/blogs/hadi_hariri/archive/2010/03/09/profiling-apps-1-of-n-the-mvc-actionlink.aspx) the difference is not too much